# LUKS not prompting for password after kernel update

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, grub, luks, initramfs

I have an unencrypted /boot partition and an encrypted root under lvm, created during kubuntu installation:

```
root# cat /etc/crypttab 
nvme0n1p5_crypt UUID=562c3c2c-9ef4-4417-aff8-1912e3828175 none luks,discard

root# cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                          <mount point>    <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root              /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=b42862d0-7e2e-4cd0-b55a-e1c9942a5031 /boot           ext4    defaults          0       2
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1            none            swap    sw,user           0       0

root# blkid | grep UUID
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p5_crypt: UUID="mYTUiQ-iFPJ-BkoP-DhuI-9zCc-YDg1-fdWxd4" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root: UUID="f79a3b71-4107-4702-93a2-ae15ee68aca5" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="b42862d0-7e2e-4cd0-b55a-e1c9942a5031" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8478cfa7-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="562c3c2c-9ef4-4417-aff8-1912e3828175" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="8478cfa7-05"
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="d3ad648d-e0a5-4b34-94cf-95912dcd7116" TYPE="swap"
```

I have recently updated the kernel to 5.7, and after grub loads initramfs it does not ask for passphrase, instead it stops complaining:

```
Volume group "kubuntu-vg" not found.
```

If I select an older kernel in grub it asks for passphrase and then boots fine.

Is there something wrong with the above configuration? It would be strange since I haven't touched anything in those files.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was related to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-meta/+bug/1801629) bug.
I've solved by

```
apt install cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cryptsetup-initramfs cryptsetup-run dmeventd
```

and

```
update-initramfs -c -k 5.7.6-050706-generic
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to self-answer your question!